# print_control_identifiers() error in pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am using pyautowin in WIN10, and I want to open a secure app to generate passcode. But after i find a window of app in script, the print_control_identifiers() function pops error, I'm not sure where goes wrong. Error Window? No controls in app? Please look into below errors.

Code like this:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app=Application()
app.start('C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Software Token\SecurID.exe')
RSA=app.window_(title='000131843108 - RSA SecurID Token')
print RSA
print RSA.print_control_identifiers()
```

Error like this:

```
2016-12-30 11:54:01,525 INFO: Imported existing <module 'comtypes.gen' from         'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.pyc'>
2016-12-30 11:54:01,526 INFO: Using writeable comtypes cache directory: 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen'  
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x039EA670>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/New folder/ConnectVPN.py", line 7, in <module>
    print RSA.print_control_identifiers()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 569, in print_control_identifiers
    this_ctrl = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)[-1]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 239, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'process': 4064, 'backend': u'win32', 'title': '000131843108 - RSA SecurID Token'}
```

My app is like:

[image]

Comment: I do nothing but it works now...     it returns                                        `Control Identifiers:

QWidget - '000131843108 - RSA SecurID Token'    (L863, T117, R1120, B303)
[u'000131843108 - RSA SecurID Token', u'QWidget', u'000131843108 - RSA SecurID TokenQWidget']
child_window(title="000131843108 - RSA SecurID Token", class_name="QWidget")
None`   is that means no controls i can use in this app?

Answer (score 1):

Is your app starting slowly? If it takes more than 5 seconds, the main window may not exist yet and the exception is raised. Just use `RSA.wait('ready', timeout=10)` to make sure the window exists before `print_control_identifiers()`.

Comment: This happened to me when I tried for notepad app.Properties.print_control_identifiers(). Then this method worked for app.window (of another app). May be it happens when you are searching in a wrong component? Btw when I tried for ```a in app:''' it gave ``infinite'' loop or something. I guess, this library should have a more strict access - seems like it creates an object whenever you try to get it.

Comment: Huh, this is interesting case. It seems we need to override `__iter__` method for `Application`. Currently `__getitem__` method creates window specification every iteration infinitely. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Fixed in master branch. Now it raises `NotImplementedError` and recommends `app.windows()` usage.